# Regex for validating numbers with certain length and beginning

Tags: java, regex, xsd

I would like to validate a value which should have numbers only and length should be 11 and should not start with 129.

Is this possible as I am not very efficient in regular expressions?

Comment: for XSD1.0, only the below regex works fine:
[02-9][0-9]{10}|1[013-9][0-9]{9}|12[0-8][0-9]{8}

Comment: ^(?!129)\d{11}$ would not work in xsd 1.0

Answer (score 5):

Use negative lookahead.  The regex should be `^(?!129)\d{11}$`  Turn that into a Java pattern; escape the backslash.

Comment: ^(?!129)\\d{11}$ this expression is working fine in java but is not supported in xsd 1.0

Comment: If the xsd regex rules do not support `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead.  Can you have two `xsd:pattern`s in an `xsd;restriction`?

Comment: ^(?!129)[0-9]{11} is also not supported in xsd.
If we use 2 xsd patterns in a single restriction then it will be treated as "pattern1 OR pattern2" but not "pattern1 AND pattern2"

Comment: [^1].*|.([^2].*)?|.{2}([^9].*)?  This is working for validating for 129 in xsd.But i dont know how i can add one more condition in this regex for including length 11 and number restriction conditions

Comment: [02-9][0-9]{10}|1[013-9][0-9]{9}|12[0-8][0-9]{8}

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String num_regex = "^(?!129)\\b[0-9]{11}\\b";
String testString= "12345678910";
Boolean b = testString.matches(num_regex);
System.out.println("String: " + testString + " :Valid = " + b);
testString= "12945678910";
b = testString.matches(num_regex);
System.out.println("String: " + testString + " :Valid = " + b);
```

OUTPUT:

```
String: 12345678910 :Valid = true
String: 12945678910 :Valid = false
```

Comment: The `\b` and `^` are redundant when you use `String.matches`

Comment: Thank you. It is working correctly. But can I use AND condition to combine 2 different regex in a single pattern?

Comment: The regex is working fine in Java code but in xsd 1.0 this regex is not supported.